# Qgis - GrassGis error

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

When I execute a grassgis alogrithm in Qgis I always get following error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 23: ordinal
>   not in range(128) See log for more details

and

> This algorithm cannot be run :-(  It seems that GRASS GIS 7 is not
>   correctly installed and configured in your system. Please install it
>   before running GRASS GIS 7 algorithms.

In processing opitions I set the path for grassgis to 
`C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0`, same for grassgis docs.

There is no option for setting the path to msys.

I reinstalled whole OSGeo4W with coustom options and installed all available options. No result.

Comment: Does your Windows user name include non-ASCII characters? If so, you must create a new user without them. This might apply to the source data folder too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the username really contains a non-ASCII character, so I cannot create as a new user on this machine.

As [commented by @AndreJ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226120/qgis-grassgis-error#comment349509_226120).